# How to wait for GTK+ object to be destroyed before continuing?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk2

I have a program where I open a file dialog and take the file name and do some resource intensive operations.

My problem is that while the opertion is running, even though gtk_widget_destroy() has been called on it the file dialog stays open.

This is a problem because I will need to implement a loading bar in the near future and I don't want the dialog hanging around. my code looks like this:

```
if(gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(fileSelect)) == GTK_RESPONSE_OK){
    filename = string(gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(fileSelect)));
    gtk_widget_destroy(fileSelect);
}else{
    gtk_widget_destroy(fileSelect);
    return;                       
}

resourceIntensiveFunction();
```

So how can I wait for the file dialog to exit before continuing?

BTW I'm using GTK 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out how to do it, it is relatively simple.

```
while(gtk_events_pending()){
    gtk_main_iteration_do(true);
}
```

Hope this helped someone.

Comment: While that will work, it's usually a bad habit to pump the event loop. It would be preferable to g_signal_connect(fileSelect, "destroy", ...) and respond to that signal. Either "destroy" or "hide" would probably work.

Comment: What would I put for the code inside that event? I see what you mean though thanks.

Comment: Basically everything you want to happen after the widget is hidden or destroyed. So, I guess, `resourceIntensiveFunction();`.

Comment: Thanks, but that needs to be called inside the function like in my answer because of a lot of variables.